# unknown attribute 'resource_type' for Pin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, rspec

I am trying to run specs using rspec on a Pinterest clone app. Was not having this issue before, not sure what changed.

Here are my migrations.

create_pins

```
class CreatePins < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
  def change
    create_table :pins do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :url
      t.text :text
      t.string :slug
    end
  end
end
```

add_resource_type_to_pins

```
class AddResourceTypeToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
  def change
    add_column :pins, :resource_type, :string
  end
end
```

create_categories

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :name
    end

    add_column :pins, :category_id, :integer, references: :categories
    add_index :pins, :category_id

    if Category.all.empty?
      Category.create(name: "ruby")
      Category.create(name: "rails")
      Category.create(name: "unknown")
    end

    unknown_category = Category.find_by_name("unknown")
    pins = Pin.where("category_id is null")

    pins.each do |pin|
      category = Category.find_by_name(pin.resource_type)
      if category.present?
        pin.category_id = category.id
      else
        pin.category_id = unknown_category.id
      end
      pin.save
    end

    if Pin.where("category_id is null").empty?
      remove_column :pins, :resource_type
      puts "MIGRATION SUCCESSFUL!"
      puts "All your data has been migrated successfully."      
    else
      puts "ERROR! Something went wrong - not all pins have been assigned a category Id."
    end
  end
end
```

add_attachment_image_to_pins

```
class AddAttachmentImageToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def self.up
    change_table :pins do |t|
      t.attachment :image
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :pins, :image
  end
end
```

schema

```
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_04_01_220336) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "categories", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
  end

  create_table "pins", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "url"
    t.text "text"
    t.string "slug"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.string "image_file_name"
    t.string "image_content_type"
    t.bigint "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_pins_on_category_id"
  end

end
```

seed

```
Pin.create(
  title: 'Rails Tutorial', 
  url: 'https://www.railstutorial.org/', 
  text: "The trusted standard in self-directed introductions to Ruby on Rails. A complete treatment of all the essentials
    required in most production Rails applications.", 
  slug: "rails-tutorial",
  resource_type: "rails")

Pin.create(
  title: 'Rails for Zombies', 
  url: 'http://railsforzombies.org', 
  text: "A fun, gamified way to hone your Rails skills! Come on...who doesn't like fighting zombies?!", 
  slug: "rails-for-zombies",
  resource_type: "rails")
Pin.create(
  title: 'Try Ruby', 
  url: 'http://tryruby.org/', 
  text: "An interactive, in-browser tutorial for the Ruby programming language. A thorough walkthrough of 
    Ruby's nuances, geared toward beginners.", 
  slug: "try-ruby",
  resource_type: "ruby")
Pin.create(
  title: 'Ruby Quiz', 
  url: 'http://rubyquiz.org', 
  text: "A collection of quizzes on the Ruby programming language.", 
  slug: "ruby-quiz",
  resource_type: "ruby")
Pin.create(
  title: 'Ruby on Rails for Developers', 
  url: 'https://github.com/generalassembly/ga-ruby-on-rails-for-devs', 
  text: "Somewhat advanced curriculum, but the exercises are also good for anyone who is motivated and 
    self-guided with experience.", 
  slug: "ga-ror-for-developers",
  resource_type: "rails")
Pin.create(
  title: 'Ruby Monk', 
  url: 'http://rubymonk.com', 
  text: "The Ruby Primer is a free interactive book that helps you learn Ruby. Discover Ruby idioms, learn 
    lessons and solve problems, all in your browser!",
  slug: "ruby-monk",
  resource_type: "ruby")
```

Getting error for unknown method "resource_type" when seeds try to load.

App runs on Heroku. What am I missing? Let me know if other files are needed.

Comment: As you can see by you schema.rb there are no field `resources_type`. Did you ran rails `db:migrate` after you added migration `AddResourceTypeToPins` ?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response Alex. I figured out that I needed to update my seeds file to `category_id` instead of `resource_type`. Apparently removed `resource_type` from pin table when creating `category` class.

Comment: Sure, I was missed it

Answer (score 0):

Removed `resource_type` from `Pin` table in `create_categories.rb` migration.

Had to change `seeds.rb` `resource_type` into `category_id` from the new `Pin` table.